# JavaScript-error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, html, import

I have created a project which has 2 js file and a html file.
the first one is sum.js ( which I have sum function in it) and second one is main.js and last is index.html.
I tried to import sum function in main.js but I got this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script src="./main.js"></script>
</html>
```

and sum.js:

```js
export function sum(a , b){
console.log(a + b)
}
```

main.js:

```js
import {sum} from "./sum.js"
sum(1,2)
```

I tried to make script tag like this too :

```html
<script type="module" src="./main.js">
```

this won't give any error but it won't write anything on console.
so can you help me please?

PS I'm on google chrome

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be  at main.js

```
import {sum} from "./sum.js"

sum(1, 2)
```

Comment: No it was my fault on writing in site.

Comment: your problem was in your main.js file try to import sum.js differently